# Lag in Blender 2.83 Modeling (Edit Mode)

Tags: modeling

I'm a beginner in modeling and have been learning how to create a person basemesh in 3D. I just finished making the eyes of my person, and am about to begin the nose. However, my Blender has become extremely laggy. This was not a problem earlier until I had finished the eyes. My current file size is 7.7 MB.

I checked the computer resources, CPU utilization does not go over 22%, and memory utilization does not go over 45%. I am not sure what is causing the extreme lag. Any ideas or pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which OS are you using ? Try Reinstalling Blender, i am also getting a lot of Problems in Blender 2.83.1, it must be optimised. I recently switched to Linux, and when I start Blender, view port runs at 5 fps, while previous versions ran extremely smooth, i shutdown my PC (not restart) and retry after 10 minutes and start blender just when the PC boot, and it ran perfectly fine.

Comment: Are you using a subdivision surface modifier? If so, how many subdivisions have you set it to? Alternatively, if you're sculpting, are you using dyntopo?

Comment: I am currently using Windows 10. My viewport runs fine, it's just when I go into edit and sculpt mode that it gets laggy (those are the only two modes I've used so far to try modeling). However, I will try reinstalling Blender. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @ChristopherBennett No, I've only used a mirror modifier so far. I'm not using dyntopo in the few times that I switch to sculpt mode, only the basic brushes that are found on the side when I switch to sculpt mode.